# Is there any callback function to handle swipeback from one screen to another?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any callback function to handle swipe back from one screen to another?

Comment: What navigation module are you using? `react-native-navigation` or `react-navigation` or `react-native-router-flux` or ...?

Comment: react-native-router-flux

Comment: @K.Wu I am using react-native-navigation. Do you know the answer?